# Managing SKTextures for animations

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, game-engine

I'm wondering about the best way of managing my textures.  In my current project they are all quite small, so it doesn't really matter, but I'm wondering if there is any best practice.  I'm also working with the entity/component system (it's an experimental project).

So I have an animation component that I use to store all my animations related to that entity.  I created a struct like that:

```
struct AnimationDefinition { 
   let animation: [SKTexture]
   let timePerFrame: CGFloat
}
```

And I store animation definitions in a dictionnary property of my component so I can recall them by name later on.  That part works really well.  For now though, I have only a limited number of entities, but I plan on adding more as development goes on so the way I'm creating the animations might become messy because I'm creating all the textures in the entity's init().  So I'm pretty sure if I reuse that component in another project that uses large textures and more animations, it will slow down everything each time I create an entity.

So I thought about building a TextureManager who will create the textures at the beginning (if it becomes bigger i could make it regenerate itself at the beginning of each level with only the textures that will be used) and feed the arrays at will.  Is that a good way to go?

Should I create the animation's SKAction right away and store that instead of the texture array?

Thanks for your opinions?

Answer (score 0):

here are some resources, buried in there are some nuggets pertaining to what you want.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit.html

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/608/

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DemoBots/Listings/DemoBots_SceneManager_swift.html

Comment: Although these links might be useful, you should avoid posting [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). That is because link can become broken and will not be useful for future readers. So you may want to add quotes from those links as well as the code, because otherwise your answer will be flagged and likely removed.